# Django tables2. Render link for empty cells

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I needed render link for empty cells with some default text.
By default, django-tables2 for null values render "—", without any link attached to it.
I managed to do this using TemplateColumn like this:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
# template
TEMPLATE = """
{% if record.some_field %}{{ record.some_field }}{% else %}<default text>{% endif %}
"""
# column definition 
link_column = tables.TemplateColumn(linkify=True, template_code=TEMPLATE)
```

I just wanted to ask if there is more convenient way to achieve this, cause it sure seems like this.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, a tables2 field can also be a property of the model. So you might do the linkification in the model:

```
class Foo( models.Model):
    ...
    bar = models.CharField( ...)
    ...

    @property
    def bar_t2_link(self): 

        # form desired_target and desired_text from Foo data
        # desired_target will probably use reverse() 

        return format_html(
            '<a href="{}">{}</a>', desired_target, desired_text)
```

Comment: good to know this method exists, gonna try it, thanks. but it doesnt seem much more convenient than my solution. i hoped for some argument for Column class which i missed, that do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can disable django-tables2's handling of empty values in a column with `empty_values=[]`.

If `some_field` could be an empty string this would produce a link with no content (i.e. `<a href="…"></a>`, so you might need to handle empty values in a `render_some_field` method on the table class.

This gives you:

```py
from django_tables2 import Table, columns

class SomeTable(Table):

    some_field = columns.Column(
        linkify=True,
        empty_values=[],
    )

    def render_some_field(self, value: Any) -> str:
        if value in {"", None}:
            return "—"

        return str(value)
```